# What can be deduced about the covariance between f(x) and f(x + K) for constant K?

Tags: probability, variance, covariance

The question concerns transformations of a random variable $X$ by a function $f$. I’d like to understand whether there are conditions that could make:

$$\operatorname{covar}(f(X), f(X + K) ) \geq \operatorname{covar}(f(X),f(X)) = \operatorname{var}(f(X)).$$

In other words, is it possible that the covariance of a function of $X$ with a shifted version of itself can be greater than the covariance of the function with itself? If so, when exactly?

**Assumptions**

$X$ is a real random variable with unknown distribution

$f \colon \Re \rightarrow \Re$ is a continuous, bounded, differentiable function (perhaps also positive, monotonically increasing if that simplifies things)

$K \neq 0$ is a real constant

I suspect there are particular distributions of $X$, properties of $f$, and/or values of $K$ that might make the above inequality true, but I'm not sure how to start.

I’ve tried applying various Gruss-type inequalities but it’s not clear to me how they might help. The only starting point I'm aware of is that if $\operatorname{covar}(f(X), f(X + K) ) \geq \operatorname{covar}(f(X),f(X))$, then $\operatorname{var}(f(X+K)) \geq \operatorname{var}(f(X))$.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that $f(X)$ is a transformation of the random variable $X$ or the PDF of $X$?

Comment: @Dave, correct, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $f$ may have very different behavior on values of the form $X+K$ than on values of $X,$ **there is no general relationship of this kind that will hold,** nor is there any simple alternative way to characterize it.

The following simple example uncovers the essence of the situation.

For any real number $\lambda \gt 1$ define a *smooth, invertible transformation* $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by setting $f(x)=x$ for $x\le 1,$ $f(x) = \lambda x$ for $x\ge 2,$ and connecting these two partial functions smoothly on the segment $(1, 2).$

Let $X$ be a random variable with a uniform distribution on $[0,1].$

Since $X\le 1$ almost surely, $f(X)$ and $X$ have identical distributions.  However, when $K\ge 2,$ $X+K\ge 2$ almost surely, whence $f(X+K) = \lambda(X+K)$ almost surely.

Compute

$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}(f(X), f(X+K)) &= \int_0^1 f(x)f(x+K)\mathrm{d}x - E[f(X)]E[f(X+K)]\\
&= \int_0^1 x\,\lambda(x+K)\mathrm{d}x - E[X] E[\lambda(X+K)]\\
&= \lambda\left(E[X^2] + KE[X]\right) - E[X]\left(\lambda (E[X] + K\right)) \\
&= \lambda\,\operatorname{Var}(X)\\
& \gt \operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Var}(f(X)).
\end{aligned}$$

The point is that the effect of $f$ on the values $X+K$ may change the scale, thereby rescaling the covariance of $f(X+K)$ (up or down) relative to any other random variable.  You cannot generally guarantee any relationship between that covariance and any of the variances of $X$, $f(X),$ or $f(X+K).$

---

Characterizing this situation (where the covariance exceeds the variance) in any other way would be difficult: it has to depend on the distribution of $X,$ the details of $f,$ and the value of $K.$

Comment: An excellent explanation with a clear example, many thanks.